# How can I test multiple possible valid values in phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a simple method `get_db_password()` which can return a string or under some circumstances it could return `null`, either case should be considered a valid response.
What I am really testing for is that the script doesnt blow up if the getter is called.
How can I write a test/assertion - which either calls `get_db_password()` and asserts that the script didnt die, or that can test whether the response was either `null` or a string. e.g something like

```
$this->assertInternalType( "string || null", $this->config->get_db_password() );
```

Source code

```
<?php

class Config {

    /** @var string $db_password stored the database password */
    private $db_password;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db_password = require(PROJ_DIR . "config/productions.php");
    }

    /**  @return string 
     */
    public function get_db_password() {
        return $this->db_password;
    }
}
```

test code

```
<?php

class ConfigTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {

    public $config;

    public function test_get_db_password_returns_a_string_or_null() {

        $this->config = new Config;

        // how can I write this test?
        $this->assertInternalType('string || null', $this->config->get_db_password());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this as a satisfactory solution

```
$this->assertTrue(is_string($pass) || $pass === null);
```

Comment: It's creative but when your test fails you won't be able to tell, which condition was failed.